# Why do RSA public keys begin with 3048024100?

Tags: rsa

RSA public keys seem to begin with 3048024100, why? They also seem to end with 0203010001

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Only if they are 512-bit and you are looking at the [PKCS1 encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#appendix-A.1.1) which uses [ASN.1 usually DER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690). 512-bit RSA is not secure; see numerous existing Qs and inter alia the recent Logjam and FREAK attacks. PKCS1 is not the only encoding, and is rarely used alone, instead usually being embedded in [X.509/PKIX SubjectPublicKeyInfo](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1); there are other quite different encodings.

3048 is the tag and length of the SEQUENCE for a 512-bit key. 024100 is the tag length and sign octet of a 512-bit positive integer, which the modulus (N) value for a 512-bit RSA key is. 0203 010101 is the tag length and value of the integer 65537, which is the fourth Fermat prime aka F4, and as a result is frequently used for the RSA public exponent (E).